# How to use gapi to authenticate on TV?

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/devices) link describes how to authenticate manually. I would like to use Google API instead in order to authenticate my device, which has limited input capabilities. Is it possible and how? How to obtain activation code using gapi, which will be shown to user?

Answer (score 0):

You may check on this documentation: [Using OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited Input Device Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices). However, the TV and Limited Input Device OAuth endpoints described herein only support a [limited set of scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#allowedscopes).

Same with other OAuth 2.0 scenarios, you first need to set up a project in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) to obtain a client ID and client secret.

> After you have the client ID and client secret, you send an HTTP `POST` to the OAuth 2.0 device endpoint at `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code` with your `client_id` and a list of scopes. Unlike the other OAuth 2.0 flows, `response_type` and `redirect_uri` are not needed in the device flow. The following is an example request for a user code:
>
> ```
> POST /o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1
> Host: accounts.google.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com&
> scope=email%20profile
> ```

You may read through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#callinganapi) for more information.

Comment: I am actually coming from these documents. So the question was should I manually use HTTP raw requests and handle in my own code or I can use Google Client Library.